# Scala return boolean with if else

Tags: scala, function, set, boolean

So I have to following scenario:

```
 def check(): Boolean = {
    for ((digit1,digit2,digit3) <- SetOfDigits){
      if ((1,2,5) == (digit1,digit2,digit3))
        true
      else
        false
}
  }

val SetOfDigits = Set((0,2,3),(1,5,6),(7,10,2),(1,2,5))
```

Now the problem is that the function has to return a Boolean but it always tells me that the return type here is `Unit`? 
The function should iterate over the `SetOfDigits` and if it finds something equal like `(1,2,5)` it should return true else false?
Has anybody an answer to this problem and what I have to do in order to get it working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't agree with the solution from Mr. V., I'd rather suggest you change your implementation, that seems a very Javish way of handling things:

```
scala> val SetOfDigits = Set((0,2,3),(1,5,6),(7,10,2),(1,2,5))
SetOfDigits: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(Int, Int, Int)] = Set((0,2,3), (1,5,6), (7,10,2), (1,2,5))

scala>   SetOfDigits.contains((1, 2, 5))
res0: Boolean = true

scala>   SetOfDigits.contains((1, 2, 4))
res1: Boolean = false
```

`contains` find an element in your set, if the element is not there, it returns false, looks much better in my opinion.

In response to your comment, I'd flatten the first list and then use `forAll` and `contains`:

```
scala> val setOfDigits1 = Set((0,2,3),(1,5,6),(7,10,2),(1,2,5)).flatMap { case(a,b,c) => Set(a,b,c)}
setOfDigits1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(0, 5, 10, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3)

scala>   val setOfDigits2 =  Set(1,2,3,16,20,7)
setOfDigits2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(20, 1, 2, 7, 3, 16)

scala>   val setOfDigits3 =  Set(1,2,3,10)
setOfDigits3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 10)

scala>   setOfDigits2.forall(i => setOfDigits1.contains(i))
res8: Boolean = false

scala>   setOfDigits3.forall(i => setOfDigits1.contains(i))
res9: Boolean = true
```

Note that I have flattend the first list from a `List[(Int, Int, Int)]` to a `List[Int]`, then `forAll` evaluates a predicate which must be true for all elements and `contains` does the rest.

Comment: Okay that worked out now for me, but I got another question!
Lets say my list SetOfDigits contains the tuples like yours above, and I want to compare another Set which contains: Set(1,2,3,16,20,7)...
How can I yield true if all the digits which are in SetOfDigits appear once in the other Set, so only check for those which both contain and ignore the other ones?

Comment: @Bajro I've made an edit, the answer was too long to fit a comment.

Answer (score 6):

You should add `return` statement before true or `false` to stop on first execution.

Otherwise you can use `yield` to collect results from each of sub-set (you'll get list of Booleans)

Depends what is your expectation. If you want to make sure *at least* on of sub-sets satisfying results, your function will looks like following:

```
def check(): Boolean = {
    val s = for ((digit1,digit2,digit3) <- SetOfDigits) {
      if ((1,2,5) == (digit1,digit2,digit3))
        return true
    }
    false
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Ende Neu's answer.

In the general case you can introduce a boolean variable that you check inside the for-comprehension to end it prematurely. I prefer it over using the `return` keyword.

```
def check(): Boolean = {
  var found = false
  for ((digit1,digit2,digit3) <- SetOfDigits if !found) {
    if ((1,2,5) == (digit1,digit2,digit3)) found = true
  }
  found
}
```

Comment: It's just bad programming to go through the whole list when you should halt upon finding the required value. True, `return` isn't idiomatic Scala, but neither are mutable variables.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, yield the result from the `if-else`, otherwise the for comprehension returns `Unit`. In a similar way to @EndeNeu API based method, consider also

```
xs.exists( _ == (1,2,5) )
Boolean = true
```

which halts the iteration over the collection as the first match is found.

Note also by convention the tag of a collection starts with a lower case letter, namely `setOfDigits` instead of `SetOfDigits`, while types and classes are capitalised.